# repeating UIImage in mkmapviewoverlay

Tags: iphone, uiimage, mkmapview

I want to display an image as an overlay to MKMapView.

The image is displayed, but the problem is it does not fit the visible rect of the mkmapview, it is showing 4 images instead of one.

How do I fix it.
screenshot of the image 
[image: image overlay of mkmapview]

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
```

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

```
CGRect rect=[self rectForMapRect:mapRect];
NSLog(@"rect width:%f height:%f",rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
[scaledImage drawInRect:[self rectForMapRect:mapRect] blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
//[scaledImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367) blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:.07];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

}

even I tried resize of image but no use..

Comment: Pls check the frame of the Overlay image u are adding. And pls post your code

Comment: Hi..,I posted the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue as follows,

Actually,I added overlayview to mapview before setting the region to mapview,

If i added overlay view after region of the mapview is set, it works fine and showed single image.

```
[self.myMapView setRegion:aRegion animated:YES];

[self.myMapView addOverlay:customoverlay];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you but its worth a try to get an idea on drawing an overlay image

[MKOverlay View is blurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117182/mkoverlay-view-is-blurred)

Another link:

[How to display an image on a MKOverlayView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891850/how-to-display-an-image-on-a-mkoverlayview)

Comment: hi,, i have tried those, but my overlay still showing 4 images